# MOOCs for college-level discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education, self-learning, learning, online-resources

Specifically I am looking for short lectures (and quizzes) on specific topics.

(like Khan Academy offers)

Topics I am learning about include;

#### Intro logic-theory + set-theory

- Notation, negation, simplification, result of set operations)
- Relations, functions

#### Intro proofs

- By contradiction, induction, well-ordering

#### Intro graph theory

- Graph coloring (chromatic numbers), Eulerian paths, Eulerian circuit, Hamiltonian paths, Minimal spanning trees (Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms), shortest path computation

#### Intro combinatorics

- Permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion, binomial theorem

Comment: have you checked out https://www.coursera.org/

Answer (score 2):

MIT has a portal where they put lots of courses on MANY subjects, and in a less informal way than Kan. Their material is really good, and you will probably find those topics in some of the courses there.

http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm

EDIT: As mentioned in the comment by eccstartup coursera is another option, but with only a fraction of what you can find on MIT's opencourseware, but it still might have many different courses.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look at [coursera](http://coursera.org). They have a large variety of courses, university level, with $15$ minute lectures (depending on the prof). Generally, these courses are $6-8$ weeks long and have accompaning exercises, quizzes and end of the year exams. I am currently taking a few courses and I have to say that I am quite impressed with the quality of material.

For **Intro to proofs** check out: [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/course/maththink) by Keith Delvin. It starts Sept. $2^{nd}$. You can also check out [Intro to Logic](https://www.coursera.org/course/intrologic) by Michael Genesereth and this starts Sept. $30^{th}$.

For **graph theory** you can check out [Social and Economic Networks: Models and Analysis](https://www.coursera.org/course/networksonline). While it may not explicitly teach what you have mentioned, I am sure it will have those aspects as it is dealing with networks.

For **Probability** There is a probability course but it is in Mandarin (?). You can [check it out here](https://www.coursera.org/course/prob) if you can understand it. You can also check out [Intro to Probability and Statistics](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2005/) from MIT open courseware.

As one of the answers has said, the MIT network is quite large. You may also want to look at the [Sakai Project](http://www.sakaiproject.org/) but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks, but those classes don't finish before my exams for this class... will checkout the Sakai Project and MIT open courseware (which I have been going through for a few days). Might get private tutelage also.

Comment: @TolearnMath Sometimes, some of these classes running again. For example, Intro to Mathematical thinking. So if you do a little snooping around, you'll be able to find all those lectures online. It's worth the time if you really need it.